# Stuck on a college Assembly project

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have been tasked with an Assembly project that contains the directions below:

The task is to build a program that creates a string based on command line instructions. The instructions, listed below, will be processed accordingly:

Use "A" to add the following byte to the variable. For instance, "Az" adds the letter "z" to the variable.
Use "D" to delete all instances of the following byte from the variable.
Use "R" to replace all instances of the following byte with the byte after it in the variable.

The input will conclude with a period. It's important to note that the program must account for non-existent letters during the deletion process. Additionally, the variable must not exceed 100 bytes.

Example input:

```
ATAOAAAT
```

Example output:

```
T
TO
TOA
TOAT
```

I don’t even know if I’m on the right path, and I can’t even imagine D and R. This is what I have so far, and I need help:

```
;nasm 2.13.02
section .data
    str: db 100
    len equ $-str
    newline db 0x0A
    
section .bss
    val: resw 1
    fullstring: resw 1
    counter: resb 1

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax,3
    mov ebx,0         
    mov ecx,str        
    mov edx,len
    int 80h

    mov [counter],byte 0
    
again:
    mov eax,4         
    mov ebx,1         
    mov ecx,newline        
    mov edx,1
    int 80h
    
    mov eax,3
    mov ebx,0         
    mov ecx,val        
    mov edx,1  
    int 80h
    
    mov al, [counter]
    INC al
    mov [counter], al
         
    cmp [val], byte '.'
    jz end
    cmp [val], byte 'A'
    je add
    cmp [val], byte 'D'
    je delete
    cmp [val], byte 'R'
    je replace
    
add:
    mov eax,3
    mov ebx,0         
    mov ecx,val        
    mov edx,1
    int 80h
    
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1        
    mov ecx,val   
    mov edx,1
    int 80h

    jmp again
    
delete:

replace:

end:
    mov eax,1            ; The system call for exit (sys_exit)
    mov ebx,0            ; Exit with return code of 0 (no error)
    int 80h;
```

(Just FYI, I use an online compiler)

I tried taking the input from the user, storing that in a variable called "fullstring", and I tried to cycle through it. What I expected to happen was to be able to pinpoint the letter that needs to be altered.

Comment: I'm not aware of an online IDE / assembler that includes a debugger for 32-bit NASM Linux assembly.  https://onlinegdb.com/ has GAS for x86-64 Linux, but that's not much help.  Trying to write asm without a debugger is like trying to build a robot blindfolded; a bit waste of time vs. setting up a debugger that lets you single step and see register values after each instruction.  (And follow the path of execution, to see when you're leaving a loop or whatever.)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/ may help

Comment: Are you trying to work out the algorithms for the various commands?  Any language can manipulate bytes in a string (eg. add/append, remove/delete) according to some commands; you don't have to think in assembly to figure algorithms out.  I recommend working it out in C then taking your if-then and loop statements literally to assembly.  That way your algorithm can be worked out and tested/debugged in C, and you'll know the only problems in the assembly version are simple statement/expression translation errors rather than algorithmic issues.

Comment: @ErikEidt I don't know C at all, this is one of my first coding classes, I've only taken C++ and still I don't know that either all too well. This is for a school assignment. I'm just stuck on how to even do the assignment, not to debug it because  I don't know what if I've written so far is correct whatsoever. I haven't even started the delete or replace functions yet.

Comment: Ok, well, assembly is an intermediate topic, if not advanced, so taking assembly before knowing other languages is very bold!  But it has been done, so best of luck.  I stand by my recommendation that you don't have to think in assembly to work out an algorithm.  Try to consider data structures and algorithms before code in assembly.

Comment: You can use C++ instead of C for what Erik's talking about, getting the algorithms right.  Especially if you avoid any library functions and just use `char buf[100]` and `char *ptr` variables, not `std::array` and especially not `std::vector<char>`

Answer (score 1):

### Understanding the task at hand

Your program needs to base its actions on 'command line instructions'. So those could come from the actual command line (from invoking the program), or they could come from single-character console input (like you are doing now), or they could come from multi-character console input (like I will be doing below).

Since the task also has *Delete* and *Replace* operations to perform, just outputting some single characters to the console will certainly not be enough. You need to store the characters obtained from the *Add* command in a memory buffer.
Currently you have defined a *str* variable in the .data section (`str: db 100`), but contrary to what you probably believe, that only reserves room for 1 byte and not the 100 bytes that you were hoping for. I suggest you place the *str* variable in the .bss section using `str: resb 100`.
Your line `fullstring: resw 1` in the .bss section is similarly suspicious as it reserves room for just 2 bytes, no exactly what we would expect for a 'fullstring'.

> Additionally, the variable must not exceed 100 bytes.

This limit is imposed on the output. To even arrive at a 100-byte output string, you would need some 100 'A' commands that are each accompanied by their 'following byte'. Therefore the length of the buffer for the input string can be set at 200 plus 1 for the mandatory terminating '.' character.

> I tried taking the input from the user, storing that in a variable called "fullstring", and I tried to cycle through it.

In assembly you would load the address of this buffer variable in a register of your choice and then start loading and processing consecutive bytes each time incrementing the value in the pointer register:

```
    mov ebx, fullstring
more:
    mov al, [ebx]
    inc ebx
    ; process AL
    jmp more
```

In the below code snippet, I exchanged ESI for EBX so I could replace `mov al, [ebx]` `inc ebx` by the one-instruction `lodsb` that too loads AL but that also auto-increments the ESI register.

> ```
> mov al, [counter]
> INC al
> mov [counter], al
> ```

To increment your byte-sized variable, simply write: `inc byte [counter]`.

> ```
>   cmp [val], byte 'A'
>   je add
>   cmp [val], byte 'D'
>   je delete
>   cmp [val], byte 'R'
>   je replace
>
> add:
> ```

Always consider what will happen if none of the comparisons got taken. Here the execution would fall through in the *add:* part of the program. That's probably not a good thing to happen! Find out how I solved this in the included program.

### An example program

Next code would turn the input `ATAOAAAT.` into the output `TOAT`. The code does not implement the *Delete* and *Replace* operations, but it should give you a better idea on how to find these out for yourself. Please read the embedded comments and maybe fine-tune the code if my reasons to abort the program don't correspond with your idea about that:

```
section .bss
    InString:  resb 201
    OutString: resb 101

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax, 3           ; sys_read
    mov ebx, 0         
    mov ecx, InString
    mov edx, 201
    int 80h              ; -> EAX (note)
    cmp eax, 1
    jl  quit             ; Abort on any error or an empty string
    mov ecx, eax         ; [1,201]

    mov edi, OutString
    mov esi, InString
again:
    lodsb                ; Get command from the input string
    cmp al, '.'
    je  end
    dec ecx
    jz  quit             ; Abort on possible command but without operand(s)
    cmp al, 'R'
    je  replace
    cmp al, 'D'
    je  delete
    cmp al, 'A'
    jne quit             ; Abort on any unknown command
add:
    movsb                ; 'to add the following byte to the variable'
    dec ecx
    jnz again
    jmp quit             ; Abort because the mandatory '.' will be missing

delete:
    ...

replace:
    ...

end:
    mov al, 10           ; Add newline to the output string
    stosb
    mov eax, 4           ; sys_write
    mov ebx, 1        
    mov ecx, OutString   
    mov edx, edi         ; Length = StringEnd - StringBegin
    sub edx, ecx
    int 80h

quit:
    mov eax, 1           ; sys_exit
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h
```

(note) *sys_read* returns in EAX the number of bytes actually read or an error indication (EAX=-1). See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html.